# EC2 user permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions

I just set up my first instance of AWS EC2 server and I'm running into an issue with permissions on a script uploading pictures.
'var/www' (and all subdirectories) owner is 'ec2-user' however the apache server is running as 'apache'.
Therefore all directories created dynamically by the php script (using mkdir) have 'apache' as the owner (which it seems doesn't have write permissions)
I could certainly change the apache user to 'ec2user' but I'm worried that might be a security risk. What's the correct way of doing this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the answer below is correct, can you mark it as such ? This would help other customers having the same question and looking for answers. Thanks

Comment: The answer is correct though it didn't solve my problem but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a pure Linux permission problem, not an AWS problem.
I just created an Amazon Linux instance and verified permissions in /var

```
 [ec2-user@ip-1-1-1-174 ~]$ ls -ald /var/www
 drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Oct 22 23:34 /var/www
```

As you see, ownership is `root` and not `ec2-user`.  You should understand first what / why you see permission on `/var/www/` to `ec2-user`

Should need to change the owner of that directory again, you can type :

```
 chown -R root:root /var/www
```

It is not a best practice to let your web server (`httpd`) write to `/var/www` nor to run that process with elevated privileges (such as root).
Should your app really write to the local storage, use a different volume, mounted in a separate directory, where no executable are available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually you are correct, owner of '/var/www/' is 'root'. However I have a sub folder '/var/www/html/files' that I use to store pictures and the owner of this folder is 'ec2-user'. For info I used filezilla through SSH to deploy the application (user ec2-user). Could this be the reason why ec2-user is the owner of the sub-folders? What's the best way to upload my files to aws instance then? I tried using elastic beanstalk but  I'm getting an error uploading the zip containing my application files though the zip file seems fine....

Comment: yes, when you authenticate as ec2-user in FileZilla, it will create file owned by ec2-user.  Continue to do so if easier for you and change ownership after the transfer (using the chown command as described in my answer above)

Comment: yes but my script creates folders dynamically (using mkdir in php) within the files folder and the owner of the created folder is 'apache'(as php runs as 'apache')...

Comment: What it should be ec2-user or, root?

Comment: it depends on the user used by the app.  In @Arbiz example above, the correct user is "apache"

Answer (score 13):

To set file permissions for the Apache web server

1- Add the www group to your EC2 instance with the following command:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo groupadd www
```

2- Add the ec2-user user to the www group:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo usermod -a -G www ec2-user
```

3- To refresh your permissions and include the new www group, log out:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ exit
```

4- Log back in again and verify that the www group exists with the groups:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ groups
> ec2-user wheel www
```

5- Change the group ownership of the `/var/www` directory and its contents to the www group:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo chown -R root:www /var/www
```

6- Change the directory permissions of `/var/www` and its subdirectories to add group write permissions and set the group ID on subdirectories created in the future:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo chmod 2775 /var/www
[ec2-user ~]$ find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} +
```

7- Recursively change the permissions for files in the `/var/www` directory and its subdirectories to add group write permissions:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} +
```

Comment: More from this link :http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html

Comment: Not surprisingly, the instructions given on the AWS link listed above are splendid. Thanks for the direct link.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using **Amazon Linux 2 AMI** then steps are different

To allow the ec2-user account to manipulate files in this directory, you must modify the ownership and permissions of the directory. There are many ways to accomplish this task. In following steps, you add ec2-user to the apache group, to give the apache group ownership of the /var/www directory and assign write permissions to the group.

To set file permissions

Add your user (in this case, ec2-user) to the apache group.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
```

Log out and then log back in again to pick up the new group, and then verify your membership.
Log out (use the exit command or close the terminal window):

```
[ec2-user ~]$ exit
```

To verify your membership in the apache group, reconnect to your instance, and then run the following command:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ groups
ec2-user adm wheel apache systemd-journal
```

Change the group ownership of /var/www and its contents to the apache group.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
```

To add group write permissions and to set the group ID on future subdirectories, change the directory permissions of /var/www and its subdirectories.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo chmod 2775 /var/www && find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;
```

To add group write permissions, recursively change the file permissions of /var/www and its subdirectories:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;
```

Now, ec2-user (and any future members of the apache group) can add, delete, and edit files in the Apache document root, enabling you to add content, such as a static website or a PHP application.

How to setup Amazon Linux 2 LAMP, full details are here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html

Answer (score 1):

As a ec2-user user I will be able to create a directory to /var/www. ec2-user is user and group name as well.

Step 01
Change group of /var/www directory to ec2-user group

Step 02
Grant read, write, execute permission to ec2-user group

```
 sudo chown -R root:ec2-user /var/www   
 sudo chmod -R 770 -R /var/www
```

After that you will able to create directory to /var/www. Hope this suggestion is helpful to your problem.