# EC2 - creating a new user that has access to same directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I've setup an EC2 with "bitnami" that creates a linux user `bitnami@myproject.com` as a user for me to access with my keyfile.

Once signed in via ssh by doing `ssh -i mykeyfile.pem bitnami@12.23.43.32` and hitting `ls` I get **apps  bitnami_credentials  htdocs  stack**

I now want to create a new user that is also able to connect to this location. Therefore I read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html

I did `sudo adduser developer`, created a keypair on the EC2 dashboard and by using keygen I created the public key for this user.

And … I'm able to connect to the server with `ssh -i developer.pem developer@12.23.43.32` however this user does not see any files if I type `ls -a`. I only get **.  ..  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .cache  .profile  .ssh**

How can I make sure this new user also is able to work with the directories that "bitnami" has to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you do ssh to instance, after login the user directory is set to its home directory. In your case, it should be `/home/developer`.

To view directories that you see in  `bitnami` user home directory you have to switch directory after login as `developer`.

- run `ssh -i mykeyfile.pem bitnami@12.23.43.32` after login type `pwd` or the path of the directory where you see **apps bitnami_credentials htdocs stack**, for example, it should be `/home/bitnami`.
- Now log as developer `ssh -i developer.pem developer@12.23.43.32` and now change your directory to the one that you got in first command. `cd /home/bitnami`

If you see permission then you need to set permission. You can add `developer` user to `bitnami`. You can check for permission [here](https://www.helicaltech.com/create-multiple-sudo-users-to-ec2-amazon-linux/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611608/ec2-user-permissions)

Comment: Hey @Adiii … thanks so much. This works, however I wonder if it is somehow possible to simply make the "root" directory when connecting via ssh with a new user a different directory? E.g. I want "developer" for instance to only access the ```bitnami/htdocs``` directory and when connecting he should directly land there? Is that possible somehow?

Comment: yes it possible `usermod -d /home/bitnami -m developer` but it's not recommended and maybe you will face permission issue with`~/.ssh`. By default should land on his own directory is the practice of chep or AWS opswork.